# Cannot get Core Motion Updates using watchOS 5: "[Gyro] Manually set gyro-interrupt-calibration to 800"

Tags: gyroscope, core-motion, watchos-5

I am trying to get Core Motion data from an Apple Watch 3 (WatchOS 5.1) but although the DeviceMotion is available (`isDeviceMotionAvailable` property is `true`), the handler is never triggered. I get the following message in the console right after parsing `super.willActivate()`:

> [Gyro] Manually set gyro-interrupt-calibration to 800

I am using the following function to get Device Motion updates:

```
func startQueuedUpdates() {
    if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
        self.motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 100.0
        self.motion.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
        self.motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical, to: self.queue, withHandler:{
            (data, error) in
            // Make sure the data is valid before accessing it.
            if let validData = data {

                print(String(validData.userAcceleration.x))

            }
        })
    }
}
```

In the InterfaceController I have declared

```
let motion = CMMotionManager()
let queue : OperationQueue = OperationQueue.main
```

Has anyone met this message before and managed to resolve it?

Note: I have checked the `isGyroAvailable` property and it is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to match the `startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame` parameter to your device's capabilities. If it has no magnetometer, it cannot relate to magnetic north, and even if it has a magnetometer, it cannot relate to true north unless it knows where you are (i.e. has latitude & longitude). If it hasn't got the capabilities to comply with the parameter you select, the update will be called, but the data will be `nil`.

If you start it up with the minimum `.xArbitraryZVertical` you *will* get updates from the accelerometer, but you won't get a meaningful heading, just a relative one, through the `CMDeviceMotion.attitude` property ...

```
if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
    print("Motion available")
    print(motion.isGyroAvailable ? "Gyro available" : "Gyro NOT available")
    print(motion.isAccelerometerAvailable ? "Accel available" : "Accel NOT available")
    print(motion.isMagnetometerAvailable ? "Mag available" : "Mag NOT available")

    motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
    motion.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
    motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xArbitraryZVertical) // *******

    // Configure a timer to fetch the motion data.
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
        if let data = self.motion.deviceMotion {
            print(data.attitude.yaw)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. It now works perfectly. I will also try with the new Apple Watch Series 5 that has magnetometer to see if it different.