# WatchOS gyro calibration interrupted

Tags: swift, apple-watch, gyroscope, watchos

I implemented some shake gesture in my WatchOS app (repo here: https://github.com/ezefranca/WatchShaker) and it was working, but I am now getting the following error in debugger:
`[Gyro] Manually set gyro-interrupt-calibration to 800`

what does this mean and how do I fix it?

the `watchShaker(didShakeWith:)` function should run when the watch is shaken, but it is not running

```
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
    }
        var shaker:WatchShaker = WatchShaker(shakeSensibility: .shakeSensibilityNormal, delay: 0.2)

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        shaker.delegate = self
        shaker.start()

        getRandomNumbers()

    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        super.didDeactivate()
        shaker.stop()
    }

extension OneDiceController: WatchShakerDelegate {
    func watchShaker(_ watchShaker: WatchShaker, didShakeWith sensibility: ShakeSensibility) {
        self.getRandomNumbers()
    }

    func watchShaker(_ watchShaker: WatchShaker, didFailWith error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @noahbino I found the problem, looks like these happens when the Watch have Gyro sensors support. Following the [@grimxm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3729417/grimxn) [tip here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748841/cannot-get-core-motion-updates-using-watchos-5-gyro-manually-set-gyro-interr) in the version 1.0.1 I fixed that.

Thank you.